# AmCharts4 Remove Padding / Margin between Graph and Container

Tags: padding, amcharts, amcharts4

Is there a way to remove the padding between the container and the graph in AmCharts4?

I have tried `chart.padding(0, 0, 0, 0)` but it doesn't have an effect.

https://codepen.io/ChazUK/pen/JjKVvNv

```
const chart = am4core.create('chart', am4charts.GaugeChart);
chart.innerRadius = am4core.percent(80);
chart.logo.disabled = true;
chart.responsive.enabled = true;

... rest in codepen
```

[image: Remove Padding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the outer radius of the gauge, and also set padding to 0 on all edges of the chart itself:

```
chart.radius = am4core.percent(100);
chart.innerRadius = am4core.percent(80);
chart.paddingTop = 0;
chart.paddingRight = 0;
chart.paddingBottom = 0;
chart.paddingLeft = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, It's not very obvious that you have to change the outer radius in the docs.

I have also noticed that <400px the container adds padding back

`<g transform="translate(0,10)">`

Comment: Fixed with https://gist.github.com/ChazUK/9e35b0c38982f4adf1fe1c94831473fb